# Firefox plugin for queuing downloads?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I am looking for a Firefox plugin that puts downloads in a queue so that only one item is downloading at the time. I can't seem to find such a plugin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201)** should do the job. Just set in preferences "*Max concurrent downloads*" to 1.

Comment: Thanks, I had used this plugin before, but I didn't realize I could use that pref to create a download queue.