# In Firefox, is there a way to enqueue downloads to happen one at a time (sequentially)?

Tags: firefox, download

Using Firefox on a computer with a single hard-disk drive, sometimes I need to download several many large files from a remote server that is also serving from a single hard-disk drive.

It does not make sense to download all of these files "at once" as both my computer's write head and the remote server's read head would be jumping around a lot, making the download much slower. I can download each file one by one, but I have to start each of those downloads manually when the previous one is finished.

So, as per the question title, is there a way in Firefox to enqueue downloads to happen one at a time (sequentially)?

Edit: I checked and extensions (plugins) like "DownThemAll" are **not** going to work with my use case due to how the links are served (I'll spare the details). I'd like to click "download" on a dozen or so files and have them download sequentially with Firefox's built-in download manager.

Comment: Similar: https://superuser.com/questions/134105/firefox-plugin-for-queuing-downloads.  Even though that question is from 2010 the plugin still exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox plugin for queuing downloads?](https://superuser.com/questions/134105/firefox-plugin-for-queuing-downloads)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for the input. I know there's good reasons to let Firefox asynchronously download many files simultaneously, it is the default case: that is very reason why I have asked this question including many details as to how my case is *different* from that default case. Would you please read my question again, as I have explained how the server works, how my client works, and that the files are *large* (i.e. much bigger than the cache)?

Comment: @squillman I was hoping for some built-in way to do it with Firefox (a menu I'm missing, or an about:confg setting)

Comment: @harrymc I was hoping for some built-in way to do it with Firefox (a menu I'm missing, or an about:confg setting)

Comment: You can try in *about:config* changing the *network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server* to 1 (6 is default). Note that this is a change that will affect every webpage you visit using Firefox, making it stop downloading resources in parallel, and thus, making it seem to work much slower.

Comment: Or perhaps in this setting: *security.remote_settings.intermediates.parallel_downloads* - I haven't tested these configurations, but they might help to achieve what you need.

Comment: @Ramhound I guess synchronously was the wrong word choice since what I really meant was "*not* asynchronously" i.e. sequentially

Comment: @Romen thanks for the input. I am a programmer too, and I specialize in concurrent programming. When tired, I typoed "synchronous" instead of "not asynchronous" but that's also why I included the word "sequentially" in parenthesis next to it and wrote a detailed use case where I specified "one by one." I fixed it, but you seem like a smart person and I reason can detect that I made a simple grammatical mistake and figure out what I meant from the rest of the detailed example and extra info in parenthesis.

Comment: Even if someone is taking your typo as-is without being able to infer the correct meaning from the rest of your question it still makes sense. Making multiple downloads run in sequence requires synchronization, these words don't contradict each other at all.

Comment: Do you need to use Firefox or a browser for this at all? Would some shell scripting work for you instead?

Comment: @aoeu As a programmer, could you use your programming language of choice to download the files sequentially? Or maybe you can add an API to the server so that it serves the chosen files as one zip archive?

Comment: @aoeu What is the maximum download speed of the client? Is it greater than 10 MB/s ?

Comment: @Romen - Let’s not confuse everyone by using a third unrelated word

Comment: @AndrewMorton As one programmer (maybe to another), do you truly believe I wouldn't have considered using the tools of my profession (that I use day and day out!) to solve this problem vs. dealing with all of these comments on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for the interest in answering this question. The bottleneck is the speed of the drives on each side as per my example, not the network. If you're really curious, downloading two files sequentially averages 6x faster than downloading them at the same time, and things get orders of magnitude slower once you try downloading even more of these files at the same time (see my explanation about the HDD drive heads).

Comment: @Romen No, I need to use Firefox. That's why I specified Firefox. Please see the comment (below) I provided to user J13C on the first attempted answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a stupid answer, but have you tried this add-on?
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3download-statusbar/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search
It has a "Queue Mode", allowing to download only one file at a time, after clicking on a bunch of "Download" buttons like you mentioned.

Comment: Any attempt at an answer is a great answer, thank you very much for posting one at all (vs. adding yet another comment on my question)!

Comment: Unfortunately, add-ons won't work. Without going too into details, the pages seem to be intentionally designed to not be scraped programmatically or to work with one of these download extensions (DownThemAll, Download Manager, etc.)  As in, the pages don't have a normal anchor tags, downloads are only initiated by some javascript magic when manually interacting with a javascript-drawn right-click menu on a <div> with no CSS class and only contains plain text (not a URL, or <a href="...">, etc.).

Comment: I did not understand that this extension / plugin actually interoperates with Firefox's built-in download manager.  This means your solution *does* work as I can enable Queue Mode before starting the downloads. I'm going to accept your answer, thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help! 